# How can I covert an integer to base 3

Tags: java

I found a challenge online, and thought its pretty interesting but tried multiple times to understand what base 3 is and how u can get there, but unfortunately no clue how.

Write a method, convertIntegerToBase3() which does the following:

-- Accepts an integer parameter (from 0 to 26) and converts it to base 3, which is stored
as a string, which is the return value.

```
public String convertIntgerToBase(int num){

    if(numberConv >= 0 && numberConv <= 26){
        //What do I do here?
     }
    else{
        System.out.println("Error! Number entered wasn't in the range of 0 and 26);
    }
}
```

Comment: That code won't even compile. It's `int` not `Int`. Also you forgot to terminate the string in the `println` call.

Comment: `Integer.toString(numberConv, 3)`.

Comment: how is it a duplicate ?

Comment: Also see [Base 10 to base 2,8,16 conversion in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008685/base-10-to-base-2-8-16-conversion-in-java) which links to the same duplicate.

Comment: To help you understand what base 3 is : in base 10, you count like that : `0, 1, 2, 3 ..., 9, 10, 11, ...` ; in base 2 you count like that : `0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, ...`. In base 3, you count like that : `0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20, ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Because below answer at just works up to base 10 I've come up with following answer which works up to base 36:

```
private static final char[] CHARS = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

private static String convertIntToBase(int i, int base){
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    do{
        builder.append(CHARS[i % base]);
        i /= base;
    } while(i > 0);
    return builder.reverse().toString();
}
```

The logic stays the same, but now by accessing the `CHARS` array we can get up to base 36. Because we have now the whole alphabet and the numbers to create a new number in an other base.

Using this will now yield correct numbers for e.g. base 16:

```
convertIntToBase(255, 16);
```

Will return the correct hex value:

```
ff
```

**Old**

It's pretty simple, by division and using the remainder of the base and can be made also generic:

```
public String convertIntToBase(int i, int base){
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    do {
        builder.append(i % base);
        i /= base;
    } while(i > 0);
    return builder.reverse().toString();
}
```

which then can be used like the following:

```
convertIntToBase(24, 3);
```

Which yields:

```
220
```

This works, as said with division and the remainder (modulo). With the sample number `24` we can go through the steps pretty easy. The iteration and calculation `(i /= base) % base` can be split up into the following parts:

1. divide `i` through the `base` (`i /= base`)
2. split of the comma places (This is done automatically because division of integers in java are always floored)
3. See what remainder stays by whole-dividing the `i` with the `base` (`i % base`)
4. repeat if `i` is bigger than zero

So with the `i = 24` and `base = 3` it goes through the following steps:

1. 24 % 3 = 0
2. 24 / 3 = 8
3. 8 % 3 = 2, because by whole-division we get that 3 is 8 times in 2, leaving 2
4. 8 / 3 = 2
5. 2 % 3 = 0
6. 2 / 3 = 0

leaving you with the known result: `220`

Comment: Can you also explain how the logic works?

Comment: Thank yous so much it makes sense!

Comment: [Doesn't actually work, though](https://ideone.com/krMKXf). Unless you expect converting 3 to base 10 to yield zero. Or converting 0 to base 10 to yield "". Or converting 100 to base 10 to yield 010.

Comment: @Zabuza see the edit

Comment: @AndyTurner that's pretty odd, I guess i just had luck with the number chosen for `i` and `base`...

Comment: @Lino [here is a (more) fixed version](https://ideone.com/cYZjXn).

Comment: @AndyTurner many thanks. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Base 3 is simply representing a number as a polynomial where the base of the polynomial is 3. It can extend for all basis, like base 1.2, base 99... etc.

```
Number in Decimal = (A0)*3^0 + (A1)*3^1 + (A2)*3^2 ...
where AX can have in value that falls with in (x)mod(3) or
(x)mod(base). In your case a range of [0,1,2]. (x)mod(Anything) is 
always positive or zero.
```

Try to think how you could guess with your base might, be but, its essentially a problem asking you to divide a number. If you know how to divide your integer number with that polynomial, you've figured out the problem.

Comment: That's pointing OP into the right direction. But it doesn't fully answer the question, nor provide a solution. Please see [answer].

Comment: Well they accepted the other answer, just wanted to throw the theory out there.